# CouchDbException: 500 Internal Server Error: function_clause for application deployed on Bluemix

Tags: ibm-cloud, cloudant

I have my Java Web application running in Bluemix which is using Cloudant Database. During Load testing I saw few requests failing with following exception in logs

```
[App/0]ERR[ERROR ] SRVE0777E: Exception thrown by application class 'org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service:423'
[App/0]ERR at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:386)
[App/0]ERR at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:423)
[App/0]ERR at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:221)
[App/0]ERR at com.cloudant.client.org.lightcouch.CouchDbClient.execute(CouchDbClient.java:513)
[App/0]ERR at com.cloudant.client.org.lightcouch.CouchDbClient.delete(CouchDbClient.java:301)
[App/0]ERR at com.cloudant.client.org.lightcouch.CouchDbClient.executeToResponse(CouchDbClient.java:282)
[App/0]ERR at com.cloudant.client.api.Database.remove(Database.java:883)
[App/0]ERR at com.cloudant.client.org.lightcouch.CouchDatabaseBase.remove(CouchDatabaseBase.java:259)
[App/0]ERR at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor12.invoke(Unknown Source)
[App/0]ERR at com.conversation.jersey.DBCloudantUtil.removeFlowStackDb(DBCloudantUtil.java:178)
[App/0]ERRCaused by: com.cloudant.client.org.lightcouch.CouchDbException: 500 Internal Server Error: function_clause
[App/0]ERR at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory$1.invoke(ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory.java:81)
[App/0]ERR at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher$1.run(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:144)
[App/0]ERR at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.invoke(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:161)
[App/0]ERR at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:389)
[App/0]ERR at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:267)
```

I referred to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34808892/connection-error-while-connecting-to-cloudant-db-from-local) post but they are getting the same error when they execute Java application locally. Any one facing similar issue?

Comment: Are you running any custom functions on the database? I've seen similar errors when debugging JavaScript map functions.